# Testing android app without text to speech engine installed

Tags: android, emulation

I want to test my program on a platform where Text to speech engine is not installed.

I want to use emulator but can't seem to remove Text to speech engine from it.

I am using AVD  manager to do that..

Please advise how can I achieve it.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default TTS engine is part of the system, so you can't remove it. You could probably remove the data files, but is not a good idea, since the emulator doesn't have the Market/Play app, so you can't download them (easily).

Test on a real device, and possibly remove the language data files, to test if the app handles this case correctly.

Comment: Thanks. So does it mean I can ignore the possibility of missing TTS engine on the system ?

Comment: Not quite. Then engine will be there, but it might support the language you are using, so you have to check; or it might be supported, but the data files might not be installed.

Answer (score 1):

You can test by removing the data files on an emulator.

First remove the data files by doing this:

```
adb remount
adb shell rm -r /system/tts/lang_pico/*
```

then reinstall the files by running this:
http://code.google.com/p/eyes-free/downloads/list